# Add map if it dosen't exist else increase quantity if it exists in the array

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list/collection and I need to check if a product exist by the same id, I need to increase the quantity else add the product. I am able to add product if id dosen't exist but I am not able to increase quanity if the product dosen't exist.

```
cart_items = [
        {
            "id": 144,
            "created_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:04",
            "updated_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:04",
            "cart_id": "3",
            "client_id": "83",
            "product_id": "6",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "1500",
            "name": "Cucumber (2Pcs)",
            "image": "products/es4eGjkgQ6MvzTaMyX4iXWjcSX03mVk3QB9oODWk.jpeg",
           },
        {
            "id": 145,
            "created_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:09",
            "updated_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:09",
            "cart_id": "3",
            "client_id": "83",
            "product_id": "5",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "2000",
            "name": "Cauliflower",
            "image": "products/lVZ31zORzltyVIDXhHoCWUgjTlal7cWd7pI8DL2V.jpeg",
            }
    ]
```

**Edit:**

I have implemented this till now:

```
if (snapshot.data.data()["Array"][0]["id"] == 1489) {
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("text")
                      .doc("qjxuj18kfcOpqBVLWjVD")
                      .update({
                    'Array': FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                      [
                        {
                          "id": 14999,
                          "created_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:09",
                          "updated_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:09",
                          "cart_id": "3",
                          "client_id": "83",
                          "product_id": "5",
                          "quantity": 1,
                          "price": "2000",
                          "name": "Cauliflower",
                          "image":
                              "products/lVZ31zORzltyVIDXhHoCWUgjTlal7cWd7pI8DL2V.jpeg",
                        }
                      ],
                    ),
                  });
                } else {
                  print(snapshot.data.data()["Array"][0]["id"]);
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("test")
                      .doc("qjxuj18kfcOpqBVLWjVD")
                      .update(
                    {
                      'Array'[0]["id"]: 
                    },
                  );
                }
```

I am using Fieldvalue.ArrayUnion to check if a value exist, now I want to implement Fieldvalue.increment() . Reason: updating and uploading the whole array is not convinent . Everything is working fine but getting stuck at the else part ...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Did you try anything already? Stack Overflow is most useful when you show us what you tried, and not just the input data and the expected output. By seeing where you got stuck, we can help you get unstuck, instead of just writing code for you.

Comment: Also, your top level data structure shouldn't be a list, but a map keyed on id, so that ids will be forced to be unique, and it will be quick to determine when an entry exists or is new.

Comment: i am able to check if the id exists in the array, no issues with that , apart from that I need it to be an array insted of a map because of some other calculation reasons, I use the .reduce method to calculate the total sum.

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick:

```
def add_item(local_cart_items, my_item):
    for item in local_cart_items:
        if item["id"] == my_item["id"]: #If item is in the shopping cart increase the 'quantity'
            item["quantity"] = str(int(item["quantity"]) + 1)
            return

    #If item is not in the shopping cart just add it
    local_cart_items.append(my_item)
```

- It takes 2 arguments, the whole `cart_items` and an `item`.
- It checks the ID of each item in the list and matches it against the given item.
- If it finds a match: function increases the `quantity` attribute.
- If it doesn't find a match: function inserts the `item` into the `cart_items`.

Comment: I am sorry but you completely changed the direction of the question ... :/

Comment: sorry , I am a new contributor . it's my fault. Hope you understand.